# Realm blocks Gson library

Tags: android, database, parsing, gson, realm

I have an issue with the Realm library. I implemented it in my app, included the library. Started creating some realmObjects, in order to use with my app, and then I tried starting the app, but to my surprise, it got stuck on the first page, which is strange, cause no Realm code was there.
After some debugging I found out that it crashed at the following line:

```
 String json = gson.toJson(user);
```

Gson is not null. Also I tried and took out realm, to see if that is the issue and it worked without it.
This is what crashlytics tells me, after a couple of minutes (it doesn't crashes directly, just sits a while blocked, and after that):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available  
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)  
dalvik.system.VMRuntime.concurrentGC (VMRuntime.java)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
com.crashlytics.android.internal.am.a (SourceFile:44)
com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run (SourceFile:13)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:162)
com.crashlytics.android.v.a (SourceFile:1936)
com.crashlytics.android.v.uncaughtException (SourceFile:307)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException (ThreadGroup.java:693)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException (ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

EDIT: The Item that I pass to gson (user) is an instance of a class called UserRecord which extends RealmObject.
Could it be this is happening because it's a realmObject and not a standard android Object?

Comment: Have you done a memory profile?

Comment: Does your user object contains big blobs of data?

Comment: its 6 rows, like username, firstname, lastname, email , etc, basically a User object. Didn't do a memory profile. But it seems strange for gson to try to  free space for about 2-3 minutes, untill it crashes from OOM from a json smaller than a twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue: The problem was that I was using:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Instead of what I should have used:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return false;
        }
    })
    .create();
```